# How to configured marshaller object on spring boot soap application

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-boot

I have created Spring boot project for SOAP Application without create Jaxb2Marshaller  marshaller bean on cofiguation and it is working fine
i.e. application is able to  unmarshall and marshall XML request and response.
Here Question is,  I want to modified marshaller/unmarshaller properties by creating Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller bean in @Configuaration class 
and used same for marshaller/unmarshaller but it is not invoking while marshaller/unmarshaller while processing soap request/response.

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

```
 @Bean
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller(){
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("com.mycompany.v1");
    marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(getPropeties());
}
```

Same configuration was working file on simple spring project.